# Touchpad settings not showing up Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: touchpad, 22.04, system-settings

After having to fix some display manager settings (issues with gdm3 & lightdm) my touchpad two finger scroll stopped working.
I checked the settings and figured out the touchpad setting are completely missing.

I'm using a Lenovo laptop.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to power cycle your local machine. It happens when you have updated some software and the system needs to power cycle to start correctly.

So do power off/on, it did the trick for me.

I have had the same issue, Installed multiple tools and applications to fix the issue and found a  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007179 [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007179), which explains the same issue but there is no solution.

Apparently restarting multiple times did nothing but power off/on did the magic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).